# Flatten operation between Dense layers

Tags: deep-learning, keras, keras-layer

In a Keras implementation, I once saw the two last fully connected layers defined as follows

```
outX = Dense(300, activation='relu')(outX)
outX = Flatten()(outX)
predictions = Dense(1,activation='linear')(outX)
```

Between the two Dense layers, there is Flatten layer, why we must add a Flatten operation between two fully connected layer. Is that always required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:** a Flatten layer doesn't have any parameter to learn itself.  However, adding a Flatten layer to the model can increase the learning parameters of the model.

**Example:** try to figure out the difference between these two models:

1) Without `Flatten`:

```python
inp = Input(shape=(20,10,))
A = Dense(300, activation='relu')(inp)
#A = Flatten()(A) 
A = Dense(1, activation='relu')(A)
m = Model(inputs=inp,outputs=A)
m.summary()
```

Output:

```python
input_9 (InputLayer)         (None, 20, 10)            0         
dense_20 (Dense)             (None, 20, 300)           3300      
dense_21 (Dense)             (None, 20, 1)             301       

Total params: 3,601
Trainable params: 3,601
Non-trainable params: 0
```

2) With `Flatten`:

```python
inp = Input(shape=(20,10,))
A = Dense(300, activation='relu')(inp)
A = Flatten()(A) 
A = Dense(1, activation='relu')(A)
m = Model(inputs=inp,outputs=A)
m.summary()
```

Output:

```python
input_10 (InputLayer)        (None, 20, 10)            0 
dense_22 (Dense)             (None, 20, 300)           3300      
flatten_9 (Flatten)          (None, 6000)              0         
dense_23 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 6001      

Total params: 9,301
Trainable params: 9,301
Non-trainable params: 0
```

**Finally,** To add or not to add a Flatten layer depends on the data at hand. Having more parameter to learn can lead to a more accurate model OR can cause overfitting. So, one answer should be: "apply both, choose best"

Comment: Nice explanation but when I add and remove flatten layers between dense layers to check if number of params are changing, i see there is no change in number of params But the model behavior improves with an extra flatten between dense layers. How come ??